# Get rid of xmlns attribute when adding node to existing xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I have an XML-file:

```
<ns2:root xmlns:ns2="namespace">
    <ns2:a>
        <ns2:b>some content</b>
        <ns2:c>some content</c>
        <ns2:d>some content</d>
    </a>
</root>
```

I need to add a new node in the specific place, my code is:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
XNamespace ns2 = "namespace";
doc.Element(ns2 + "root").Element(ns2 + "a").Element(ns2 + "c").AddAfterSelf(
    new XElement(ns2+"new", 
        new XElement("new1", 
            new XElement("new2","some content"),
            new XElement("new3", "some content"))));
```

The output is:

```
<ns2:root xmlns:ns2="namespace">
    <ns2:a>
        <ns2:b>some content</b>
        <ns2:c>some content</c>
        <ns2:new>
            <new1 xmlns="">
                <new2>some content</new2>
                <new3>some content</new3>
            </new1>
        </new>
        <ns2:d>some content</d>
    </a>
</root>
```

Desired output is:

```
<ns2:root xmlns:ns2="namespace">
    <ns2:a>
        <ns2:b>some content</b>
        <ns2:c>some content</c>
        <ns2:new>
            <new1>
                <new2>some content</new2>
                <new3>some content</new3>
            </new1>
        </new>
        <ns2:d>some content</d>
    </a>
</root>
```

How can I avoid adding xmlns atrribute to the node new1?

---

Edited mistake in desired output.

Comment: From an *information* perspective, they're the same. Generally, you shouldn't care about how XML tools choose to represent the information, and it shouldn't be an issue unless you're feeding this XML into something that doesn't actually work with XML - if it works with "strings full of angle brackets that look like XML" but requires absolute formatting, then usually it's better to push to get the broken component changed rather than try to force a particular representation in the XML.

Comment: Your sample XML is invalid, and when corrected I can't reproduce the behaviour you're claiming. I strongly suspect there's *actually* an `xmlns="..."` somewhere in your XML, which changes things significantly. Additionally, your desired output is very different to your current output - it has elements of `new1` and `new2` with text, rather than `new1` containing `new2` and `new3` with text. Please show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem, and make your question self-consistent.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. My code is-  
          var target = doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "Flight" && p.Value == flightNum).Single();

           target.Value = flightNumWithoutSuffix; //Updating element value

target.AddAfterSelf("Suffix", suffix);

it is adding an element to the Xdocument as 
<Suffix xmlns="">suffix</Suffix>

my expectation is that it should be <Suffix>suffix</Suffix>

Answer (score 0):

Add "ns2 +" before every element name that needs to be in the sitemap namespace

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
XNamespace ns2 = "namespace";
doc.Element(ns2 + "root").Element(ns2 + "a").Element(ns2 + "c").AddAfterSelf(
    new XElement(ns2+"new", 
        new XElement(ns2+"new1", 
            new XElement(ns2+"new2","some content"),
            new XElement(ns2+"new3", "some content"))));
```

Comment: Already tried this, there are "ns2:" prefixes before every node, which is not what I need.

Comment: Put a de default namespace like - XNamespace defaultNs = "http://www.tempuri.org/default"; and then use new XElement(defaultNs +"new1"

Answer (score 0):

Adding a default namespace before element resolved my issue
XNamespace defaultNs = "http://www.iata.org/IATA/2007/00";
target.AddAfterSelf(new XElement(defaultNs + "Suffix", suffix));